# Suspended changesets created in Dev workspace appear in Release workspace

Tags: workspace, changeset, rational-team-concert

Here's my setup: I have a `SW_Dev` stream which is loaded in `SW_Dev_RWS` workspace. This is where the daily work is done. Every once in a while, I make a snapshot of `SW_Dev`, and create a workspace from that snapshot, `SW_Release_v1_RWS`. Then I change the flow target of `SW_Release_v1_RWS` to `SW_Release` stream deliver all changes there and also make a snapshot. The goal is to have snapshots for all releases in `SW_Release` stream. I also keep `SW_Release_v1_RWS` loaded for a while, since I often need to produce release binaries with small tweaks for testing.

The problem I have appears when I have unfinished work in `SW_Dev` which I have to store in a suspended changeset. For some reason, that suspended changeset also appears (as suspended) in `SW_Release_v1_RWS`. Of course that means there are no actual modifications to the release workspace, but it doesn't look tidy. What's worse, if I try to discard a suspended changeset from `SW_Release_v1_RWS`, it also disappears from `SW_Dev_RWS`.

Is there a way to prevent suspended changesets created in `SW_Dev_RWS` from appearing in `SW_Release_v1_RWS`? Perhaps there is a different approach I should adopt for saving release snapshots in `SW_Release` stream?